# How to access variables from another class that are in another folder of the same android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I'm using a screen design lib through the touch screen event, the result of this design, which is the coordinates I need to pass to another class, the ActivityMain of the same project, but in another folder. How do I access these values ​​that are coming from the lib I'm using. Below is the image of how my project is organized on android. The lib is in the java language inside "library" and I need to access the variables inside my mainactivity in the default folder of my project, which is in the kotlin language.

[image]

Gradle app:

```
implementation project(':library')
```

The variables are these:

```
public class ShapeDrawingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public float startX;
    public float startY;
    public float finalX;
    public float finalY;
    Log.i("value ", shape.startX.toString())
}
```

Exit log = 1162.4032

MainActivity:

```
import com.editing.canvas.library.ShapeDrawingActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val shape: ShapeDrawingActivity = ShapeDrawingActivity()

    Log.i("test return", shape.startX.toString())
}
```

Exit Log = 0.0

Answer (score 0):

First you initialize this module in your gradle in your case its a library and add dependencies of this module in gradle file.
Then Call the class
android automatically import the module in your package and you get the variables.

```
ShapeDrawingActivity:ShapeDrawingActivity = ShapeDrawingActivity()
ShapeDrawingActivity.startX
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it returns 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use using static variable, but make sure after completion of the task you need to deallocate static variable because static variable lives throughout the project even if you change activity or class.

```
public class ShapeDrawingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static float startX;
public static float startY;
public static  float finalX;
public static  float finalY;
Log.i("value ", siz.startX.toString())
}
```

and in the different class use like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

        Log.i("test return", ShapeDrawingActivity.startX.toString())
}
```

Comment: even declaring the variables as static, a value of 0.0 is returned for MainActivity

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet use logcat and check the value before access in other class.The way is correct which I provide.

Comment: In the class, seeing through the logcat the correct value appears, but in the main class it appears 0.0. And when I put the static variables in the ShapeDrawingActivity class I can't even access them in MainActivity